# Drupal 9 - Add new terms to existing field programatically

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-9

I'm having trouble adding a new term to an existing field on a Drupal 9 website.  Attempts to set field values work for fields I've tested (ie: text and boolean) but not for taxonomy term reference fields.  Not sure exactly what I'm missing.

Below is the code I'm currently working with.

```
  $nids =[123, 124, 125];

  foreach ($nids as $nid) {
    /** @var \Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node */
    $node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($nid);
    $field_category = $node->get('field_category')->getValue();
    $categories = [];
    $new_category = "100647";

    foreach ($field_category as $category) {
      $categories[] = $category['target_id'];
    };

    if (!in_array($new_category, $categories)) {
      $categories[] = $new_category;

      try {
        $node->set('field_category', $categories);
        $node->save();
      }
      catch (\Exception $e) {}
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

nice try but you are missing entity reference here. Here is your code with few changes. First thing is $new_category, what entity type is this. If it is a taxonomy type then here is the code

```
$nids =[123, 124, 125];
foreach ($nids as $nid) {
  /** @var \Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node */
  $node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($nid);
  $categories = [];    
  $categories = array_column($node->field_category->getValue(), 'target_id');
  $new_category = "100647";
  if (!in_array($new_category, $categories)) {
    $categories[] = $new_category;
  }
  $total_categories = [];
  foreach ($categories as $categoryid) {
    $category = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($categoryid);
    if(!empty($category)) {
      $total_categories[] = $category;
    }
    
  }
  try {
    $node->set('field_category', $total_categories);
    $node->save();
  }
  catch (\Exception $e) {}
}
```

Here you are missing entity reference to field that you are mapping to node.